# The application "Terminal" can't be opened

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra

When I try to open the Terminal app in macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 I get the error:

```
The application "Terminal" can't be opened
```

I tried to restart the system and updated the OS to the last version but didnt't work. I also tried to find the preferences and cache files for the Terminal app in `/Library` folder but couldn't find any.

Is there any solution to this problem?

EDIT: I've also realised that happens the same when trying to open the console: `the application "Console" can't be opened`

Also, if I see the systemlog I can see this error:

> com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Terminal.6980[3227]): Service
>   could not initialize: 17G65: xpcproxy + 11476
>   [1524][B5FFE99F-CD7F-3AD0-8C3B-A06EF069275A]: 0xd

Answer (score 3):

Try reinstalling the OS from Recovery.

Hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>   at the chimes.
This will not affect your user account or files, but re-lay a new OS over the existing one.